# How to update collection with custom fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

As example: 
I have TSV file with data: {id:"", name:"", age:""} 100 records.

1. I import it to database into new collection:

   ```
   mongoimport -d myDB -c people --type tsv C:\Users\User1\Downloads\PgWxXsCHH5rtmpOt4BXqZA.tsv --headerline
   ```
2. I decided that each record shoul have some custom field like e.g. `rank` so I add field to each record:

   ```
   db.people.update({},{$set:{rank:0}},false,true)
   ```
3. I get new TSV file with updated data, for example same ids, only new ages.

Question is: how can I update same collection with new data, with pre-saving a custom field with its value. Also if TSV has new records, which are not present in collection they should be added and also same custom fields as old records but with empty or "0" value?

Comment: This command `db.comments.update({}, {$set:{rank: 0}}, false, true);` works well in my db. Any errors for your command?

Comment: no problem with command `db.collection.update` Just I want to know if in poin 3. I should do again `mongoimport` new TSV file? and after that will the data of field `rank` will be saved. Also does new records will have field `rank`?

Answer (score 0):

The command `db.update` is not a valid MongoDB command. The command to update a collection while setting a value for a new field is:

```
db.comments.update({}, { $set: { rank: 0 } }, false, true)
```

You do not need to define the custom fields for the new records except you require them.

Comment: Yea, I noticed that made misspelling. everything ok. Question is about other thing, see comments.